# The form to change email/profile pictures doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Any guidance on this issue will be greatly appreciated. I entered the necessary fields so that on the profile page the user would be able to edit the profile picture and the username and email. when I created the form, it only displayed the update button and the "Profile Info" text. How can fix this so that the form to edit the user information appears?

in views.py

'''

```
@login_required
def profile(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(response.POST, instance=response.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(response.POST, response.FILES, instance=response.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(response, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect("/profile")

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=response.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=response.user.profile)

        args = {}
        args['u_form']= u_form,
        args['p_form']= p_form
    return render(response, 'register/profile.html')
```

'''

in forms.py
'''

```
from django import forms
#from django.contrib.auth. import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.forms import ModelForm


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email"]


class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

'''

in profile.html

```html
{% extends "register/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
      <div class="media">
        <img class="rounded-circle account-img" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
          <h2 class="account-heading">{{ user.username }}</h2>
          <p class="text-secondary">{{ user.email }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <fieldset class="form-group">
              <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
              {{ u_form|crispy }}
              {{ p_form|crispy }}
          </fieldset>
          <div class="form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
          </div>
      </form>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: Pass the context to the template. You only write `return render(response, 'register/profile.html')` instead you should pass the dictionary you have made for the context so `return render(response, 'register/profile.html', args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To render some variable in the template it must be passed as the context to the template. In the line:

```
return render(response, 'register/profile.html')
```

You never pass it the context. `render` accepts the optional third argument as the context. So the line should be:

```
return render(response, 'register/profile.html', args)
```

> **Note**: You accept the **`request`** parameter in the view as `response`! This is a great misnomer! The request is what the user makes to the server and the response is what the server returns. You should accept the parameter as `request` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! i am very very grateful for the explanation as well!